# Initialization of VM Failed

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, large-object-heap

**Machine Install memory : 8GB**

In the Jboss developer studio, while building the project or sometimes while starting the server I am getting below the exception,

Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for object heap

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

in **jbdevstudio.ini** configuration file I have set the below heap size,

- -Xms512m
- -Xmx1024m

**What size should I use so jboss studio will work properly ?**

Comment: Make sure you are using a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit version

Comment: It worked  when I changed the values to, 
                                  -Xms1024m                             
    -Xmx1024m.    But what values should we use.. ? and on what basis..?

Comment: The warning regarding the `MaxPermSize` option can easily be eliminated by removing the `MaxPermSize=256m` option from the configuration. It’s entirely obsolete in Java 8. The failure to reserve enough heap space is normally connected to the `-Xmx` setting only. With the same amount of the available memory and the same `-Xmx` option, you should get the same result. Raising the `-Xms` setting should not help here; it’s more likely that the amount of available RAM has changed in-between. It seems that the a significant portion of the 8GB is already occupied when you try to start JBoss…

Comment: Thanks @Holger.. I see what i did wrong. I have defined Xmx  to 1024 in the config and While trying to start JBoss, it was throwing an exception. Now it is clear that.. why it was throwing an exception.. bcoz the available RAM at that time was may be less than 1024..